# Referencing Oracle.DataAccess.dll in Visual Studio 2012 website

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I put the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in my bin directory and I included a reference to this using Website/Add Reference

But when i try to include the following in my C#

using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

I get the error. "The type or namespace 'Oracle' could not be found.

How can I get the Website to find this namespace?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET).  Have you installed it already?